# Joining two tables based on multiple key fields

Tags: sql, netezza

Hello i have the following scenario:
i have a fact table with 4 Key fields and a Dim table with 1 key field and i have to join the fact table to to the dim table based on all these key fields to look up certain type of doctor. Can you please guide me on how to go about doing this. Thanks.

Provider_Fact:
ADMITTINGDoc, 
ATTENDINGDoc, 
REFERRINGDoc, 
TREATINGDoc

Provider_Dim:
ID,
Name

Comment: can you post some sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you want to look at it.  It's not completely clear to me based on your question.  Maybe:

```
SELECT ad.NAME as AdmittingDocName, 
at.NAME as AttendingDocName, 
re.NAME as ReferringDocName, 
tr.NAME as TreatingDocName
FROM Provider_Fact pf 
JOIN Provider_Dim ad 
    on ad.ID = pf.AdmittingDoc
JOIN Provider_Dim at 
    on ad.ID = pf.AttendingDoc
JOIN Provider_Dim re 
    on ad.ID = pf.ReferringDoc
JOIN Provider_Dim tr 
    on ad.ID = pf.TreatingDoc
```

OR

```
    SELECT pd.ID, pd.NAME 
FROM Provider_Fact pf 
JOIN Provider_Dim pd 
    on ad.ID = pf.AdmittingDoc
WHERE name = @name
union
SELECT pd.ID, pd.NAME 
FROM Provider_Fact pf 
JOIN Provider_Dim pd 
    on ad.ID = pf.AttendingDoc
WHERE name = @name
union
SELECT pd.ID, pd.NAME 
FROM Provider_Fact pf 
JOIN Provider_Dim pd 
    on ad.ID = pf.ReferringDoc
WHERE name = @name
union
SELECT pd.ID, pd.NAME 
FROM Provider_Fact pf 
JOIN Provider_Dim pd 
    on ad.ID = pf.TreatingDoc
WHERE name = @name
```

:)

Comment: You have a mistake in your first query - when you join to the multiple aliases for Provider_Dim you need to use each alias.ID not ad.ID for all, that's just the first alias. So ad.ID=pf.AdmittingDoc for the first, pd.ID=pf.AttendingDoc, re.ID=pf.ReferringDoc, and tr.ID=pf.TreatingDoc. PS - if you fix it, comment and include my name so I see it flagged and I'll up-tick you to offset whoever gave your answer a downvote.